# JQuery DOM childs loop with reset

Tags: jquery, algorithm, dom

I have a structure like:

```
<div id="views">
    <div id="right-view" class="current-view">
    </div>
    <div id="front-view">
    </div>
    <div id="left-view">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want a statement like `$(".current-view").next()` to behave in such way that if ".current-view" is assigned to the last child ("#left-view", in this case), the first child is returned ("#right-view", in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it yourself, e.g.:

```
var next = $(".current-view").next();
if (!next[0]) {
    // No next, use first
    next = $("#right-view");
}
```

Or if you want to avoid using the "right-view" `id` value:

```
var current = $(".current-view");
var next = current.next();
if (!next[0]) {
    // No next, use first
    next = current.siblings().first();
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/obubox) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/obubox):

```
$("#theButton").click(function() {
    var current = $(".current-view");
    var next = current.next();
    if (!next[0]) {
        next = current.siblings().first();
    }
    current.removeClass("current-view");
    next.addClass("current-view");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This defines the function `getNext()` which does what you asked...

```
$.fn.getNext = function() {
    if ($(this).next().length === 0) {
        return $(this).parent().children().first();
    } else {
        return $(this).next();
    }
}

$(".current-view").getNext();
```

Comment: Is it possible you're missing a 'return result;'?

Comment: I edited it 17 minutes before you posted that.  You're seeing an old version.

Answer (score -1):

here is a solution using modulus :

http://jsbin.com/agasay/edit#javascript,html

```
 $.fn.myNext = function() 
  {
    var result = $("body p").index($(this))+1;
    return  $("body p").eq(result % $("body p").length  );

} ;

  alert($("body p:first").myNext().text());
  alert($("body p:first").myNext().myNext().text());
  alert($("body p:first").myNext().myNext().myNext().text());
```

Comment: *"`if (!$(this).next())`"* is wrong. jQuery instances are never falsey, that condition will never be true.

Comment: The function you've used in the map, and your use of the map, are still wrong. (The function has syntax errors for a start.) You're trying to be too cute, basically. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder came up with a new solution.